# Twitter REST Api Android

Tags: java, android, twitter-api

Юзаю Twitter Kit, легко получилось настроить авторизацию и отобразить свой таймлайн, в ListView. Но вот потребовалось выводить по очереди на экран каждый твитт, при нажатии на кнопу. НЕ получается совсем...Есть идеи как можно решить эту проблему?
Вот так вывожу весь таймлайн :

```
public class TweetsActivity extends ListActivity {
private TweetViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    adapter = new TweetViewAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    loadTweets();
}

public void loadTweets() {
    final StatusesService service = Twitter.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();

    service.homeTimeline(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
                    adapter.setTweets(result.data);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException error) {
                    Toast.makeText(TweetsActivity.this, "Failed to retrieve timeline",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```